# How to parse HTML page with accented words (Spanish) without losing them?

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, hxt

I'm reading an HTML web page that contains literal accented words (Spanish):

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<title>Web page</title>
<body>
<p>Título</p>
<p>Año</p>
<p>Ángel</p>
<p>¿por qué nos vamos?</p>
</body>
```

I'm using [HXT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15):

```
...
let doc = readDocument [ withValidate no
                       , withInputEncoding iso8859_1
                       , withParseHTML yes
                       , withWarnings no
                       , withEncodingErrors no
                       , withCurl []] url
...
```

Using the option

> withInputEncoding utf8

discard those chars, getting as result the following words: **Ttulo**, **Ao**, **ngel**, **por qu nos vamos?**
Using the option

> withInputEncoding iso8859_1

convert those chars to **strings**, getting as result words like: **Rom\225ntica**, **Man\180s**, **H\233ctor**. Where **\225**, **\180** or **\233** are **strings**, not chars.

What is the best method/way/approach to properly manage this situation in HXT and get all words without modifications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I bet you already have everything you need

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ read "\"Rom\225ntica\""
Romántica
```

Looks like you are looking to result of `show` applied to the string, not the string itself? Note that `print` uses `show`:

```
Prelude> print (read "\"Rom\225ntica\"" :: String)
"Rom\225ntica"
```

Comment: Oh my... I'm still probing/playing on GHCi. Thanks @Yuras.